# UICollectionView not showing items obtained with NSURLRequest

Tags: ios, facebook, json, image, gallery

I am making an application in ios with 4 screens and one of them I want to work as a photo gallery. This images that I download from a facebook page using graph. In my ViewController class in viewDidLoad method to make the connection url:

```
(void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];  
  NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/NBAStoreNYC/photos"];  
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];  

  // Create NSURLRequest
  NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:30];  

 //Create conection
 NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];  

 if (connection) 
 {  
    NSLog(@"Connecting...");   
    dataJSON = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];  
 } 
 else 
 {    
    NSLog(@"ERROR: Unable to create connection.");  
 }
}
```

For download the images, I've parsed the JSON that I returned, for get in each for..end the URLs of the images:

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection )connection didFailWithError:(NSError )error{ NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]); }

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection )connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse )response{ NSLog(@"Received response: %@", response); [dataJSON setLength:0]; }

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection )connection didReceiveData:(NSData )data { [dataJSON appendData:data]; }

-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *) connection {
NSError *error;
UIImageView *image1;
NSMutableArray *coleccion=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSDictionary *dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataJSON options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSArray *data = [dic objectForKey:@"data"];
if (!dic) {
    NSLog(@"Error parsing JSON");
} else {
    for(NSDictionary *item in [dic objectForKey:@"data"]) {
        for(NSDictionary *attachment in [item objectForKey:@"images"]) {
            NSString *nombre = [attachment objectForKey:@"source"];
            NSURL * imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:nombre];
            NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
            image1 = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
            [items addObject:image1];
        }
    }
}
//[self.view setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

And finally I have created my gallery with a Collection View:

```
-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return [items count]*5;
}

-(UICollectionViewCell )collectionView:(UICollectionView )collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
  static NSString *identifier = @"CollectionCell";
  UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
  UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
  imageView.image = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row%1];
  return cell;
}
```

Now, when I run the app did not load any image, Why? how I can resolve it for to display the images? The exercise is almost equal that this: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iPhone_iOS_6_Storyboard-based_Collection_View_Tutorial   the difference is that I want download images of facebook graph and not have them already loaded in the project

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue I see here is that your items take time to load - it doesn't make any sense loading them on the main thread because this just causes the UI to be unresponsive. If you're looking for the one line of code NOT to execute on the main thread, it would be:

```
 NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
```

The other (related) issue is that the collectionView delegate calls "cellForItemAtIndexPath" & "numberOfItemsInSection" before the items are ready. You need to perform a "reloadData" on your UICollectionView instance in order for the newly downloaded items to appear, once they're all ready and inserted into your items array.

Hope this helps

Comment: Oh, Ok, you put the next code in viewDidLoad:                 [super viewDidLoad];
    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc]init];
    NSInvocationOperation *websOperation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(loadImages) object:nil];
    [queue addOperation:websOperation]  and in the method loadImages you do connection, but when I made this, the method connectionDidFinishLoading not load, why?

Comment: Will need to see all relevant code to answer that. I would start by adding breakpoints - try seeing if loadImages gets called.

Comment: How Can I do the reloadData that you said?

Comment: After all of your items have finished loading: [yourCollectionView reloadData];

Comment: Thank you, I understand you, but I don't understand which is my instance of collectionview. For example, I have this event:

    -(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [items count]*1;
}

but I want in other event created for me to call to reloadData but I don't have the instance. 

Thank you very much

Comment: In order to obtain an instance, all you have to do is define an IBOutlet and reference your collection view from the storyboard to it, just as you assigned your controller as it's delegate and datasource (only the other way around)

Comment: Exactly, Thank you very much for your help. But the collectionview never load , I think that, because of my program never execute cellForItemAtIndexPath. Do you know why collectionview doesn't execute cellForItemAtIndexPath?

Comment: If "numberOfItemsInSection" returns 0 then "cellForItemAtIndexPath" will never be called. That's the first thing I would check.

Answer (score 0):

I have this, beacause my items take time to load and it doesn't make any sense loading them. My news methods are:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc]init];
NSInvocationOperation *websOperation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(loadImages) object:nil];
[queue addOperation:websOperation];
}

-(void)loadImages{
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/NBAStoreNYC/photos"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:30];
NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
if (connection) {
    NSLog(@"Connecting...");
    dataJSON = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
} else {
    NSLog(@"ERROR: Unable to create connection.");
}
}
```

but the method:

```
-(void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *) connection {
NSError *error;
UIImageView *image1;
NSMutableArray *coleccion=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSDictionary *dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataJSON options:kNilOptions error:&error];
//con esto saco las imagenes de la url
NSArray *data = [dic objectForKey:@"data"];
if (!dic) {
    NSLog(@"Error parsing JSON");
} else {
    for(NSDictionary *item in [dic objectForKey:@"data"]) {
        for(NSDictionary *attachment in [item objectForKey:@"images"]) {
            NSString *nombre = [attachment objectForKey:@"source"];
            NSLog(@"%@", nombre);
            NSURL * imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:nombre];
            NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
            image1 = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
            [items addObject:image1];
        }
    }
}

//[self.view setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

not execute, why? I have put breakpoints but this in this method not enter.